# jts convert single polygon to multipolygon

Tags: casting, geometry, geotools, jts

Ho everyone I am using JTS 1.15 with geotools snapshot 21:

I  wrote a method with a Polygon Collection as input parameter and the output method is a MultiPolygon Geometry. This is working fine without one exception:
I have also an union flag that will be union my polygons if overlapping or touching. If now all polygons are overlapping only a single polygon will be returned. But then there will be  a ClassCastException.

A single polygon can’t be casted into a MultiPolygon

Is there a simple way to cast a single polygon into MultiPolygon?
I couldn't find a geometry jts uml diagram but as I found out 
Polygons extends the Geometry class with the interface Polygonal
Multipolygon extends GeometryCollection, which extends Geometry and having also the Polygonal interface.

In the [JTS Geometry Jacadoc](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html) following is mentioned:
Overlay Methods

> The overlay methods return the most specific class possible to represent the 
>   result. If the result is homogeneous, a Point, LineString, or Polygon
>   will be returned if the result contains a single element; otherwise, a
>   MultiPoint, MultiLineString, or MultiPolygon will be returned. If the
>   result is heterogeneous a GeometryCollection will be returned.

I wrote a simple string manipulator method to change my wkt string, but is there another way to achieve the goal?

here is my method

```
public static MultiPolygon createSPMultiPolygon(Collection<Polygon> polygons, boolean dissolveResult) {


    // if emty collection is returned
    if (polygons.size() == 0){
        //emty collection returns emty MultiPolygon

        GeometryFactory geomFactory = new GeometryFactory();
        MultiPolygon fail = geomFactory.createMultiPolygon();

        return fail;
    }

    //it will be assumed that all polygons have the same epsg code

    int epsgCode = polygons.iterator().next().getSRID();
    prec = new PrecisionModel(1000000)
    //creates the factory object
    GeometryFactory geomFactory = new GeometryFactory(prec, epsgCode);

    MultiPolygon result = null;


    // main task

    result = (MultiPolygon) geomFactory.buildGeometry(polygons);


        //mergedOptions
        if (dissolveResult) {

            try {
                result = (MultiPolygon) result.union();
                // there will be an exception if result or merge is a single polygon that polygon cant be cast to Multipolygon
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {

                // DO SOMETHING ELSE
            }

        }

    }
```

I am using following maven packages:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <geotools.version>21-SNAPSHOT</geotools.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
  <artifactId>gt-geometry</artifactId>
  <version>${geotools.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
  <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
  <version>${geotools.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
  <artifactId>gt-epsg-wkt </artifactId>
  <version>${geotools.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I am working with following example data and helper function:

```
    String touches1_wkt = "POLYGON ((7.896407750956972 49.73405361813658, 8.14886306623246 49.73405361813658, 8.14886306623246 49.73405361813658, 8.14886306623246 49.46768344296402, 7.902371262341433 49.46569560583586, 7.896407750956972 49.73405361813658))";
    String touches2_wkt = "POLYGON ((8.14886306623246 49.61478339044737, 8.39137919586718 49.616771227575526, 8.39137919586718 49.616771227575526, 8.399330544379795 49.35835240091558, 8.14886306623246 49.35835240091558, 8.14886306623246 49.46768344296402, 8.14886306623246 49.61478339044737))";


    Polygon touch1 = (Polygon) createSPGeom(touches1_wkt, 4326);
    Polygon touch2 = (Polygon) createSPGeom(touches2_wkt, 4326);

    Collection<Polygon> polyCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    polyCollection.add(touch1);
    polyCollection.add(touch2);

    MultiPolygon multi = createSPMultiPolygon(polyCollection, true);
```

with following helpfer method for wkt reading:

```
     public static Geometry createSPGeom(String wktString, Integer epsgCode){

    Geometry returnedGeom =null;
    prec = new PrecisionModel(1000000);

    GeometryFactory geomFactory = new GeometryFactory(prec, epsgCode);
    WKTReader wktReader = new WKTReader(geomFactory);

    try {
        returnedGeom = wktReader.read(wktString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // if wktString is invalid, an emty point geometry is used
        returnedGeom = geomFactory.createPoint();
    }

    return returnedGeom;
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [GeoMesaJim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3542319/geomesajim) say's this is a simple problem, just promote the polygon to a multipolygon.

```
GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
MultiPolygon mPoly;
if (p instanceOf Polygon){
  Polygon[] polys = new Polygon[1];
  polys[0] = p;
  mPoly = gf.createMultiPolygon(polys);
} else {
   mPoly = p;
}
System.out.println(mPoly);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your ClassCastException could be handled by checking if the call to union() returns a Polygon.  If so, you could call GeometryFactorys' createMultiPolygon with a Array containing just that one Polygon.[1]

1. https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/locationtech/jts/geom/GeometryFactory.java#L326